# Why android studio isn't showing me all activity templates like before, what should I do?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-studio, android-activity

[This is what it looks like !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KuTT.png)

I checked multiple blogs and websites but found nothing.Like in other youtube videos I can see the instructor getting all activities but not in my case.
Is there any plugin to download or something else.
My version is Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Comment: They regularly remove some old templates when new versions of Android Studio come out. Since you have the latest version you will not see some of the ones from tutorials that use previous versions of Android Studio.

Comment: It also depends on Plugings You have installed